# How to allow a layout to occupy all the space not used by other layouts

Tags: android-layout

I have a RelativeLayout

```
<RelativeLayout

   <RelativeLayout ID = TOP
     <!--Height  = wrap_content -->
   </RelativeLayot>


   <RelativeLayout ID = MIDDLE

        <RelativeLayot ID = mid1
         <!-- Placement Below TOP, allign ParentStart -->
         <!-- Height  = wrap_content -->
        </RelativeLayout>

       <RelativeLayot ID = mid2
         <!-- Placement Below TOP and right of mid1 -->
         <!-- Height  = wrap_content -->
       </RelativeLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>

  <RelativeLayout ID = BOTTOM
    <!--Height  = wrap_content -->
    <!-- Placement below MIDDLE, alligne Parent Bottom
  </RelativeLayot>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My requirement is this, Hight ofTOP and BOTTOM Layouts shout be of their content and the MIDDLE layout remaing space in the middle and its contents should be centered horizontaly and vertically. I tried height =0- and layout weight but anot able to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used LinearLayout instead, for MIDDLE used layout_height='0dp" and layout_weight="1". It solved the problem